# Extend dictionary values by same key for SVM training data

Tags: python, svm

Hi I'm quite new to Python and Machine learning, I want to extract SVM's x and y from two dictionaries.
the two dictionaries look like:

```
DIC_01
{'A': ['Low'],
'B': ['High']}

DIC_02
{'A': [2623.83740234375,
-1392.9608154296875,
416.20831298828125],
'B': [1231.1268310546875,
-963.231201171875,
1823.742431640625]}
```

About the data: The keys of the dictionaries are my 'keywords'. DIC_01 was converted from a dataframe, its values are keyword's probability of sales. DIC_02 is the vectors to represent the keyword.

I want to organise this dictionary to SVM training data format. x is the value of DIC_02, y is the value of DIC_01. 
I don't know what's the most efficient way to do this task. At the moment I'm thinking...
step 1: merge values with the same keys

```
{'A': [2623.83740234375,
-1392.9608154296875,
416.20831298828125],['Low'],
'B': [1231.1268310546875,
-963.231201171875,
1823.742431640625],['High']}
```

step 2: extract the first and second value as SVM's x and y then train the model.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hi is that what you want to do?

```
DIC_01 = {'A': ['Low'],
          'B': ['High']}

DIC_02 = {'A': [2623.83740234375,
                -1392.9608154296875,
                416.20831298828125],
          'B': [1231.1268310546875,
                -963.231201171875,
                1823.742431640625]}

smv_X = []
smv_Y = []

for e in DIC_01:
    smv_X.append(DIC_02[e])
    smv_Y.append(DIC_01[e][0])

print(smv_X) # [[2623.83740234375, -1392.9608154296875, 416.20831298828125], [1231.1268310546875, -963.231201171875, 1823.742431640625]]
print(smv_Y) # ['Low', 'High']

for k,v in DIC_01.items():
   # k = key
   # v = value
```

Comment: Hi Thank you. But the two dictionaries' keywords are not in same order. For example DIC_01 = {'A': ['Low'],
          'C': ['High'], 'B': ['High']}      DIC_02 = DIC_02 = {'A': [2623.83740234375,
                -1392.9608154296875,
                416.20831298828125],
          'B': [1231.1268310546875,
                -963.231201171875,
                1823.742431640625],'C':[-6679.1572265625,
  2265.2734375,
  1504.949462890625]}

Comment: The order of the dictionaries does not matter since I call the element by their key. But if you want one could implement an alphabetical ordering, because you are right the lists will have the order of the first dictionary.

Comment: I see thank you. I have about 10,000 key:value pairs. If I want to use loop to iterate all of them, how should i write the code?

Comment: if the 10,000 pairs are stored in one dictionary then you can do:
for k,v in dictionary.items():